# refresh a tab using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs

I'm beginning at learning react and I want to refresh a tab and not the whole page. When I click on the refresh button I expected that just the tab in question is refreshed and not the page so I want to keep the page on tab 2 or 3 and not tab 1.

Before refresh:
[image: Before refresh]

After refresh:
[image: After refresh]

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { TabProvider, Tab, TabPanel, TabList } from 'react-web-tabs';
import 'react-web-tabs/dist/react-web-tabs.css';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      defaultTab: 'vertical-tab-one'
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    let default = localStorage.getItem('default');
    this.setState(()=>({
      defaultTab:default
      })
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TabProvider defaultTab={this.state.defaultTab} vertical>
        <section className="my-tabs">
          <TabList className="my-tablist">
            <Tab tabFor="vertical-tab-one">Tab 1</Tab>
            <span className="divider"></span>
            <Tab tabFor="vertical-tab-two">Tab 2</Tab>
            <span className="divider"></span>
            <Tab tabFor="vertical-tab-three">Tab 3</Tab>
          </TabList>
          <div className="wrapper">
            <TabPanel tabId="vertical-tab-one">
              <center>
                <Button className="buttonPosition" onClick={myClick}>Refresh tab 1</Button>
              </center>
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel tabId="vertical-tab-two">
              <center>
                <Button className="buttonPosition" onClick={myClick}>Refresh tab 2</Button>
              </center>
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel tabId="vertical-tab-three">
              <center>
                <Button className="buttonPosition" onClick={myClick}>Refresh tab 3</Button>
              </center>
            </TabPanel>
          </div>
        </section>
      </TabProvider>
    );
  }
}


function myClick(){
    window.location.reload();
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're trying to do? Because we can't understand when you say 'refreshing a tab'. I think what you're trying to do is updating your state.

Comment: Hello thank's for taking your time, I have a page with three tabs and when I reload the page I want to reload the tab where I am, so when i'm in the tab 2 and I clik on refresh I want to keep the page on the tab 2 ( actually this code on the refresh button reload the page and retrun back on the tab one (the default tab) ). Also I tried to "store" the actual tab in the localStorag but this actually doesn't work and return an error "unexpected token" on the default in the componentDidMount

Comment: you should handle your logic with Link and use your component lifecycle to update your component here is an example https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/admin/src/containers/HomePage/index.js

Comment: Thank you I will check this